# How i can create <input asp-for> for a collection inside foreach

Tags: asp.net-core, razor, asp.net-core-mvc

I have the following view model inside my asp.net MVC core web application:-

```
public class SubmissionCreate
    {
        public Submission Submission {set; get;}
        public ICollection<SubmissionQuestion> SubmissionQuestion { set; get; }

    }
```

where the `ICollection<SubmissionQuestion>` contain a list of questions, so how i can view all the questions inside my view , in other words how i can define `<input asp-for>` inside a foreach, here is what i have tried but did not work:-

```
@foreach (var question in Model.SubmissionQuestion.ToList())
                {

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label asp-for="SubmissionQuestion[i]" class="control-label"></label>
                        <input asp-for="SubmissionQuestion[i]" class="form-control" />
                        <span asp-validation-for="SubmissionQuestion[i]" class="text-danger"></span>
                    </div>


                }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should change it like below:

```
@foreach (var question in Model.SubmissionQuestion.ToList())
{

    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="@question.Name" class="control-label"></label>
        <input asp-for="@question.Name" class="form-control" />
        <span asp-validation-for="@question.Name" class="text-danger"></span>
    </div>
}
```